# Moving to a new house

Tags: pi-3, web-server

At home i have a raspberry pi as a webserver for my personal project and in the next couple of months i'm moving with my parents to a new house. What are the things i should check before moving the server and which things should i check when i moved in and installed the raspberry pi again.

I came to here because my question was auto removed from the raspberry pi subreddit and i didn't find any information about on the internet

Comment: The only thing you'll need to change is the WiFi SSID and password.

Comment: @Dougie, only if the router at the new location has a different SSID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: it depends.

In general: before you move, make a backup. In that way you do not loose any data.

The rest depends a bit on how different the set-up will be in the new location and what the server actually does. If it is just an in-house server, and the IP plan is the same and the SSID/PSK are the same, it should just work. If anything changes, that should also change on the Pi.

If it is an externally accessible server, look at the way it is accessed. You probably need to change the external DNS provider, the one that resolved your host (not the one that you use to resolve yourself). The hostname was probably linked to the old IP address and must now point to the new one.  And you may need to look at port-forwarding in the new location.

Comment: Why to change the external DNS? 8.8.8.8 and other DNS server will never change all over the world.

Comment: Edited the answer; hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Most of this answer isn't relevant to moving to a new house. Backups should be done once one gets everything working. A DNS server most often comes from DHCP and there's no reason to fix it unless it's broken. "If anything changes, that should also change on the Pi" is so vague it can mean anything.

Comment: The DNS server that is meant here is does not come from dhcp. It is used to resolve your host. That might be dyndns or hopto as provider (look them up), but I have a static IP with mijndomein.nl. When I move, my IP will change and therefore I need to update in at mijndomein.nl.